# Check what ActionFilters applied within OnActionExecuting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I check what ActionFilterAttributes are applied from within OnActionExecuting in my Controller?

Comment: Reflection, read all the attributes of the method + class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it helps you:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
      var attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HomeController).GetMember("Index").First());
      return View();
 }
```

And result hould be like this:

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
var onlyActionFilterAttributesForClass =
                    typeof(HomeController).GetCustomAttributes(true).Where(
                        x => x as ActionFilterAttribute != null);

var onlyActionFilterAttributesForMember = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (HomeController).GetMember("Index").First()).
                    Where(
                        x => x as ActionFilterAttribute != null);
```

Comment: This won't check only for ActionFilters and won't check attributes on the controller.

Comment: `var attributes = typeof (HomeController).GetCustomAttributes(true);` - for controller.

Comment: And what about `ActionFilter` only? I'm not saying you're wrong, but the answer is incomplete.

Comment: I would have used `OfType`... :) sorry for being picky

Comment: Thanks, yes, this approach is also possible `var onlyActionFilterAttributesForMember =
                Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (HomeController).GetMember("Index").First()).OfType
                    <ActionFilterAttribute>();`